# Mocking a lower OS version for XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, xctest

I currently have a set of tests for my Swift project set up through Swift Package Manager that execute on my current OS (MacOS 10.13).

I am using some frameworks that are only available on this version, and I use different methods (that are still available - no deprecation) if the OS version is lower using:

```
if #available(iOS 11, macOS 10.13, *){
    //Use new methods
} else {
    //Use old methods
}
```

My question is - within my tests, how can I emulate a lower version of macOS so that I can test the code executed within the other block?

I understand I could just have this if statement call two separate functions which I can test separately, I was just curious if there was a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a old emulator before run the test. On device selector.

[image]

If you not have old emulator you can download and install one form device manager.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to invoke this using the command line `swift test`?